# Synchronous subscription using MQTTClient_receive function in a MQTT Single Threaded Application

Tags: paho

The program compiles and publishes all right. However, it does not subscribe and times out. The entire program is below. It is a modification of the program found at [PAHO](https://eclipse.dev/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTClient/html/pubsync.html) and [Adamwuming Paho](https://github.com/Adamwuming/paho.mqtt.c/blob/master/test/test1.c).

The idea is to publish and subscribe to a message via a C program synchronously using Paho MQTT C Client Library. I expect the MQTTClient_receive function to receive the published message. I am using a Windows 10 machine. The MQTT broker used is Mosquitto.

```
//gcc subs.c -o subs.exe -ID:\paho\include -L . paho-mqtt3c.lib

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "MQTTClient.h"


#define ADDRESS     "tcp://localhost:1883"
#define CLIENTID    "ExampleClientSub"
#define test_topic  "MQTT Examples"
#define PAYLOAD     "Hello World!"
#define QOS         1
#define TIMEOUT     5000L

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MQTTClient c;
    MQTTClient_deliveryToken dt;
    MQTTClient_message pubmsg = MQTTClient_message_initializer;
    MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
    MQTTClient_message* m = NULL;
    char* topicName = NULL;
    int topicLen;
    int i = 0;
    int iterations = 5;
    int rc;

    pubmsg.payload = "a much longer message that we can shorten to the extent that we need to payload up to 11";
    pubmsg.payloadlen = 11;
    pubmsg.qos = QOS;
    pubmsg.retained = 0;

    if ((rc = MQTTClient_create(&c, ADDRESS, CLIENTID,
        MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to create client, return code %d\n", rc);
        rc = EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
    conn_opts.cleansession = 1;
    if ((rc = MQTTClient_connect(c, &conn_opts)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc);
        rc = EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

        /* Publish a message*/
    MQTTClient_publishMessage(c, test_topic, &pubmsg, &dt);
    
    /* receive any outstanding messages */
    MQTTClient_receive(c, &topicName, &topicLen, &m, TIMEOUT);
    while (topicName)
    {
        printf("Message received on topic %s is %.*s.\n", topicName, m->payloadlen, (char*)(m->payload));
        MQTTClient_free(topicName);
        MQTTClient_freeMessage(&m);
        MQTTClient_receive(c, &topicName, &topicLen, &m, TIMEOUT);
    }
    return rc;
}
```

I cannot see any subscription. It is a single-threaded program. I expect the program to subscribe to the published message and print "Hello World".